# How to select column 1 value if exists else column 2 value in PostgresQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to merge two columns in PostgresQL query by the following rule:

`select (column_1 or column_2) as column_3 from my_table`

Is there a way to achieve it? Though quite clear, I want to prefer `column_1` value as `column_3` but if it is `null`, I would like `column_2` value as `column_3`.

Sorry if this sounds naive, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()`. From the manual [9.18.2. COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null.

For example:

```
select coalesce(column_1, column_2) as column_3 from t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `coalesce`. It will first select the non null value from the options.

```
select coalesce(column_1,column_2) as column_3 from my_table
```

You can also use `case when`

```
select (case when column_1 is null then column_2 else column1 end) as column_3 from my_table
```

I would prefer first option.

Comment: It is worth saying that the types of columns are important. If they are not compatible, then there will be an error.